# Referencing canvas with button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Ok so I'm attempting to have a webpage with two buttons. Each of these buttons, when clicked, creates a new canvas and calls a different draw function. The first draw function would draw large circles where the users mouse is and small ones when the mouse is pressed. The other draw function does the same thing except small circles when the mouse is unpressed and large ones when it is. I'm not having a problem referencing one of these with the button but the other button doesn't seem to call its draw function. sketch2.js seems to be working fine but it seems that the draw function in sketch.js is not being called. Any advice on how I should go about fixing this is greatly appreciated!

Below is my HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <button id="myBtn">little then big</button>
    <div id="holder"></div>

    <button id="myBtn2">big then little</button>
    <div id="holder2"></div>

    <style> body {padding: 0; margin:0;} </style>
</head>

<body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src = "/Users/bburke95/Desktop/JS/p5.dom.js"> </script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../p5.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="sketch.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="sketch2.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my sketch.js class

```
btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var q;
btn.onclick = function setup() {
    createCanvas(640, 480);
    document.getElementById("holder").innerHTML = '<canvas id="myCanvas" width="490" height="220"></canvas>';
    q = 1;
    set = 0;
}

function draw() {
    if (q == 1) {
        var x;
        var y;
        if (mouseIsPressed) {
            fill(255);
            x = 160;
            y = 160;
        } else {
            fill(0);
            x = 80;
            y = 80;
        }
        ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, x, y);
    }
}
```

and this is my sketch2.js class

```
btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn2");
var set;
btn2.onclick = function setup() {
    createCanvas(640, 480);
    document.getElementById("holder2").innerHTML = '<canvas id="myCanvas2" width="490" height="220"></canvas>';
    set = 1;
    q = 0;
}

function draw() {
    if (set == 1) {
        var x;
        var y;
        if (mouseIsPressed) {
            fill(0);
            x = 80;
            y = 80;
        } else {
            fill(255);
            x = 160;
            y = 160;
        }
        ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ignore that ^^ - it's fine.  You're destroying the `draw()` function in sketch.js by creating a new function with the same name in sketch2.js.  Simply give them both different names (draw1 and draw2, for example) and they'll both work fine :)

Comment: Where are you even calling `draw()`? Is it in your `createCanvas()` method? How can we help figure out why `draw()` isn't being called if you don't show us where you call it? I suspect it is due to you having two global functions, both with the same name, so one is overwriting the other. But there's no way to tell if that's the only problem or if it is the problem at all, if you don't show us where you are calling it.

Comment: As Archer said... your two draw functions are both globally scoped by the look of it so the latter is overriding the former, change their names to be unique

Comment: @AndrewMairose I had read here ( http://processingjs.org/reference/draw_/ ) that draw was called automatically so I assumed that when setup was referenced it would just sequentially call upon draw. I changed the names of the draw functions but now I am wondering where I should call them if I'm even supposed to. Also, now that the draw function names are changed it doesn't draw either of them.

Comment: Why are the buttons in the header?
Put it in your body!

Comment: @code802 - would be good to mention that you are using processing.js then, and that processing.js is what calls the `draw()` function.

Comment: Processing.js sketches should be written in Processing language, if you want to use javascript, you'd have to overwrite `processing` object. Please [take a tour](http://processingjs.org/learning/)

Comment: That's my mistake. I'm not using processing, I just looked at an incorrect source. Should I just be calling upon my draw functions inside of the setup functions?

Comment: You are using p5.js, which is a Javascript library that tries to mimic the Processing Language for the browser. So you shouldn't change the draw() function method, but instead instantiate your sketches in different namespaces (see my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run more than one P5.js processing sketches on the same page, you have to use "instance mode" to ensure that all the functions aren't cluttering the global namespace (which is a good idea anyway) so they don't overwrite one another.

From their [Github project](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/p5.js-overview#instantiation--namespace), you can instantiate new sketches like this:

```
var s = function( p ) {

  var x = 100; 
  var y = 100;

  p.setup = function() {
    p.createCanvas(700, 410);
  };

  p.draw = function() {
    p.background(0);
    p.fill(255);
    p.rect(x,y,50,50);
  };
};

var myp5 = new p5(s);
```

Comment: This is making sense but I'm wondering what would be changed for a second function. Since setup and draw would be the names in both .js files, what specifically would be changed in the second file?

Comment: Right, they still have the same names, but their namespace is different. What would be different between your sketch.js and sketch2.js files is the variable name with which you instantiate the sketch (the letter s in my example).

Comment: Ok thanks so much. I just have one more question. How would I go about calling these functions in my HTML file? I'm trying to only run the sketch.js and sketch2.js files with the click of a button, but there doesn't seem to be a function for me to reference. This is more of a syntax question than anything

Comment: You're welcome. You can instantiate the sketch (so the line 'var myp5 = new p5(s);') in the onclick event of the button. Then p5.js will automatically call the setup function and start calling draw() at the selected framerate.

Comment: I'm a little confused about how I would go about doing that because the only way I've ever made buttons was by setting the buttonname.onclick equal to the instantiation of the setup function. Since var myp5 = new p5(s) already contains an equal sign I don't know the syntax of instantiating that in the onclick event

Comment: You can just call a regular function like instantiateSketch() in the onclick event, and do var mySketch = new p5(s) and anything else you want to do within that function.

Comment: I've gone back to this and was wondering if I could accomplish the same thing but instead with p5 buttons. I attempted to just use "myp5" as the input function for the button but it doesn't end up relying on the onclick if I do that.